# How to change the locking mechanism in Alternative PHP Cache (APC)?

Tags: php, facebook, caching, locking, apc

I recently read in a presentation on Scribd that Facebook had benchmarked a variety of locking mechanisms for APC including file locks *(default)*, IPC semaphore locks, linux Futex locks, pthread mutex locks, and spin locks.  You can view this presentation by clicking the following link: [APC@Facebook](http://www.scribd.com/doc/88689/ApcFacebook)

I was wondering if anybody knew off hand if any of this source code had been released, perhaps in a git or SVN repository somewhere?  The speed benefits of switching from the default file locking to one of the other choices appears to be significant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, they are included in source code available at http://pecl.php.net/package/APC.

Note that you have to choose this at compilation time, more precisely: at *./configure* time. Here are the relevant options of *./configure*:

```
--enable-apc-sem            Enable semaphore locks instead of fcntl
--disable-apc-pthreadmutex  Disable pthread mutex locking
--enable-apc-spinlocks      Enable spin locks  EXPERIMENTAL
```

As you see, pthread mutex locking is already the default now.

Comment: Hmm, when I build 3.1.9, the default for me is file locks. On a related note, I've been running into the error identified here: http://www.freshblurbs.com/apc-os-x-php-fatal-error-unknown-apc-fcntl-unlock-failed Using either semaphores or spinlocks seems to work for me.

Comment: @QuinnTaylor you can fix the problem with this command in APC 3.1.9 before to compile it: `sed -i .bak -e "s/# define apc_lck_rdunlock(a) apc_fcntl_unlock(&a TSRMLS_CC)/# define apc_lck_rdunlock(a) apc_fcntl_unlock(a TSRMLS_CC)/g" apc_lock.h`

Answer (score 0):

```
vi /etc/php.d/99_apc.ini
```

then set:

```
; Locking type = spinlock
extension = apc-spinlocks.so
```

or

```
; Locking type = IPC Semaphore
extension = apc-sem.so
```

etc.